# What happens when we add a jar in HIVE?

Tags: hadoop, hive

when we add a jar in Hive what happens in background?

please explain clearly. I am new to Hadoop Bigdata and its eco systems.

Answer (score 1):

`Hive` can manage the addition of resources to a session where those resources need to be made available at query execution time. The resources can be files, jars, or archives. Any locally accessible file can be added to the session.

Once a resource is added to a session, Hive queries can refer to it by its name (in map/reduce/transform clauses) and the resource is available locally at execution time on the entire Hadoop cluster. Hive uses Hadoop's Distributed Cache to distribute the added resources to all the machines in the cluster at query execution time.

```
  ADD { FILE[S] | JAR[S] | ARCHIVE[S] } <filepath1> [<filepath2>]*
   LIST { FILE[S] | JAR[S] | ARCHIVE[S] } [<filepath1> <filepath2> ..]
   DELETE { FILE[S] | JAR[S] | ARCHIVE[S] } [<filepath1> <filepath2> ..]
```

FILE resources are just added to the distributed cache. Typically, this might be something like a transform script to be executed.

JAR resources are also added to the Java classpath. This is required in order to reference objects they contain such as UDFs.

ARCHIVE resources are automatically unarchived as part of distributing 
them.

Comment: Thanks Krish for the clairification. Now clear my query

Comment: Hi Krish,  if we convert managed table to external table through alter command, do we need to give any external path? the if we drop the table then both metadata and data will be lost or intact?

Answer (score -1):

Lets say you have developed User Defined Fuction and packaged in MYUDF.jar file.

Added jar to Hive

- hive> add jar MYUDF.jar;

**Below activity performed internally.**

The call pattern for a UDF is the following:

**1.** The UDF is initialized using a default constructor.

**2**. udf.initialize() is called with the array of object instructors for the udf arguments (ListObjectInstructor, StringObjectInstructor).

- We check that we have the right number of arguments (2), and that
  they are the right types (as above).
- We store the object instructors for use in evaluate() (listOI,
  elementOI).
- We return an object inspector so Hive can read the result of the
  function (BooleanObjectInspector).

**3.** Evaluate is called for each row in your query with the arguments provided (eg evaluate(List(“a”, “b”, “c”), “c”)).

We extract the values using the stored object instructors.
We do our magic and return a value that aligns with the object inspector returned from initialize. (list.contains(elemement) ? true : false)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Very clear with the internal process :)

Comment: add jar will only place resources to classpath,it will not invoke any of the steps that have mentioned.